# Start typing in a selected cell of a stringgrid

Tags: delphi, tstringgrid

With Dephi XE, when the user clicks a button, I want to be able to select a cell (no problem) in a StringGrid (SG) and then allow the user to immediately start typing into that cell.

```
SG.Row := DesiredRow;
SG.Col := 1;
SG.SetFocus;
```

This sets the desired cell to blue, but the user has to click on a cell to type into it. I want the user to be able to start typing immediately after clicking the button, without using his mouse.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set `EditorMode` of the stringgrid to true: `SG.EditorMode := True;` 'goEditing' should be set in the `Options` property for this to work.

Alternatively you can set `goAlwaysShowEditor` besides `goEditing` in grid `Options`.